# Which is the fastest way to insert component in Java Swing between other components?

Tags: java, swing, layout, components

I'm making a kind of editor which have a blocks (JPanel's) instead of words (with text-like flow and cursor - blinking JPanel).

I need a fast way to add a Swing component (new block) between existing components in situations like:

- mouse click between JPanels to place cursor there
- add new block element between existing elements.

The problem is, that rebuilding document (.removeAll() and .add() all blocks) take 3-4 seconds with document containing 300-400 blocks.

I can easily speed up cursor positioning, by inserting empty blocks between each block and place cursor there, but what if I need a new clean block between existing blocks ?

I know that some way is to create my own "rendering engine" but can I achieve this a lot easier with swing components ?

Comment: Why are you using JPanels as texts?

Comment: Do you really need the order? What about simply `add()`ing the new component and use a layout manager to position it where you want it? Alternatively, have you tried `add(Component comp, int index)` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component, int)?

Comment: @shuangwhywhy I use JPanel as a group of words, one under another + some small action buttons etc.

Comment: I will try with index. It's not that simple with LayoutManager, because it's a complicated layout with WrapLayout involved. See my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250043/text-like-jpanel-wrapping-in-java-swing

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say you should add just one block with proper constraint. Then it's task of LayoutManager to place the block correctly between another and layout all the children components.

Comment: Exactly, was thinking the same - are there any other constraints (e.g. tab order or similar) with such an approach?

Comment: I would keep a list of components in the container. When component is added the constraint is order (index of the added component) in the list.

Comment: Tab order doesn't matter, but deosn't writing own LayoutManager isn't too hard approach ?

Comment: This answer is correct. In special case of `FlowLayout` (or, like mine - `WrapLayout` which is subclass of `FlowLayout`), we can achive our target by `add(Component comp, int index)` like __Andreas__ said. We can find index needed by inspecting .getComponents() array

Comment: For me it's not. Just a few methods to override in layout extending currently used one.

Answer (score -1):

You need to write own LayoutManager.

Comment: not necessarily, many (those without special constraints for specific positions) managers work fine with index-based addition.